# Deleting specific observations from a data frame. Those specific observations are stored in another data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a big data frame with 6 million observation. From the column ID (that may have lots of duplicated values because I only have approximately 400k unique ID) I want to remove all ID that I have stored in a column in another data frame (around 50).

Comment: `dt1 <- dt1[!(dt1$column_id %in% dt2$column_id)]`

Comment: It says that both data frames should have the same nr of columns :(

Comment: As per the dupe target, you can create a vector with the unique IDs of your second data frame and use them to filter. For example, If your second data frame is `df2`, then `Id_to_remove <- unique(df2$IDs)` and then use it to filter out as the duplicate target says, i.e. `df1[!df1$IDs %in% Id_to_remove,]`

Comment: @Priya your code will not work since you forgot the comma to specify rows. The correct way is `dt1 <- dt1[!(dt1$column_id %in% dt2$column_id),]`

Comment: thanks @Sotos I work mostly with data.table now so lost that habit. Just remembered to put `$` there :)